# Why is there a different opacity in my xray?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

so I'm making a car in blender when I noticed a weird opacity on my mesh while in X-ray mode, why is it there? can I get rid of it? and how can I prevent it from happening?[image]

Comment: check for: 1- flipped normals, 2- doubles 3-see if backface culling is on

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like this middle section has faces whereas the rest does not, OR (long shot) flipped normals on this section

Comment: yup,flipped normals, thanks